# Solving first order linear differential equations by integration

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

This is very basic, but you have to start somewhere I guess:

When solving the following first order linear equation:
$$ \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}*\frac{1}{x} dt = \int k \mathrm{d}t $$

$k$ is not dependent on $t$, but a constant (I guess)

I don't get where the $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ part goes. In the solution in my book it states it is equal to

$\ln(x(t)) = kt+c_0$ with $c_0$ an integration constant

But it seems to me integrating $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ should result in an  extra $x$ somewhere

Comment: **Hint:** Just by basic [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_single_variable), $\int f(x) \, dx = \int f(x(t)) \frac{dx}{dt} \, dt$. (Since this is an indefinite integral, I suppose this is more accurately just the "antiderivative of" the chain rule.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "physicist way", simplify with $\mathrm{d}t$:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x$$

This is not correct mathematically, but it's really spectacular.

But you can use integrating by substitution, to be mathematically correct:

$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}t$$
Substitute $u=x(t)$, so $\mathrm{d}u=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}t$:
$$\int\frac{1}{u}\mathrm{d}u=\int \frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: I don't know when I can use the spectacular way, so I accepted your answer for the mathematically correct way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: @babipsylon Well, it can help you to memorize/understand some similar things - even if it's not correct mathematically. For example, this is how I could understand the chain rule for the first time. Or the way of solving the separable differential equations - write y' as $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$, put all of the things with $x$ and the $\mathrm{d}x$ to one side, and all of the things with $y$ and $\mathrm{d}y$ to the other.